# Is the ServiceStack RequestContext is thread-safe in .NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, servicestack

ServiceStack's `RequestContext` for .NET Core is using static `AsyncLocal` data :

```
public static AsyncLocal<IDictionary> AsyncRequestItems = new AsyncLocal<IDictionary>();
```

per request end would calling:

```
AsyncRequestItems.Value?.Clear();
```

If multiple requests set item key "test", won't it not be overridden?

Is it thread-safe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, no Request contexts instances are not thread-safe and can only be accessed by one thread at a time.

But [AsyncLocal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn906268(v=vs.110).aspx) allows you to store data for a logical thread which maintains the data across different threads when using awaits, so only 1 thread will access AsyncLocal store, the logical thread.